# How to generate all possible subsequences including Non-continuous subsequences of a string using C

Tags: c, string

For example,

```
char str[20];
str="ABCD";
```

Output :

```
1 - A, B, C,D

2 -  AB,AC, AD BC, BD, CD.

3 - ABC, ABD, BCD.

4 - ABCD.
```

The *sub-sequences* are generated only in left to right fashion. Thanks :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<string.h>


 int sub[10];

void next(int max, int length) {

    int pos = length - 1,a;

    //find first digit that can be increased
while(pos >= 0)
{
    if(sub[pos] == max - (length - 1 - pos))
        pos--;

    else
        break;
}

    sub[pos]++; //increase digit

    //update other digits
    for( a = pos+1; a < length; a++)
        sub[a] = sub[a-1] + 1;

}

int main()
{
char word[100];
printf("Enter a word = ");
scanf("%s",word);

int max = strlen(word) - 1,n,i,a,b; 


for(n=1; n <= max+1; n++)
{

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sub[i] = i;
    }

    for(a = 0; ; a++)
    {               
        for(b=0; b < max+1; b++)
            printf("%c",word[sub[b]]);

        printf("\n");

        if(sub[0] == max - (n - 1))
            break;

        else
            next(max, n); 
    }   

    printf("\n");

}   


return 0;
}
```

This code only produces *sub-sequences* of the length equal to the length of the string and it also repeats a particular character.

Comment: I am running the program from the console.... so I can't post the output but its like str="12345" the output is 11111,21111 , 31111 ...... 34511,12341 ...and finally 12345 ..

Comment: He's not asking what test inputs have you tried. He's asking what have you tried to solve the problem - have you run your code through a debugger, have you stepped through the code by hand with a given input?

Comment: @Vicky ...yes I have edited my post and I have written the code which I  tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the cleanest, most effective code, but this'll do :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char *printForMask(int mask, char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *maskedString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1); 
    for (; mask > 0; mask >>= 1, j++) {
            if (mask & 1)
                    maskedString[i++] = str[j];
    }   
    maskedString[i] = '\0';
    return maskedString;
}



int main()
{
    char str[20] = "ABCD";

    int mask = 1;
    int maskLen = 1;
    int stringLen = strlen(str);

    for (maskLen = 1; maskLen <= stringLen; maskLen++) {
            printf("%d ", maskLen);
            for (mask = (int)pow(2,maskLen) - 1; mask <= (int) pow(2, stringLen) - 1; mask <<= 1) {
                    char *temp = printForMask(mask, str);
                    printf ("%s%s", temp, (mask << 1 <= (int) pow(2, stringLen) - 1) ? ", " : "\n");
                    free(temp);
            }   
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

for the string ABCD

```
str[0] = 'A'
str[1] = 'B'
str[2] = 'C'
str[3] = 'D'
```

right?

So What I'm doing is using the binary representation of a integer `2^strlen(str) - 1`
which in this case would be `2^4 - 1 = 15 = 0b1111`
In the first for-loop of the main function, I increase the mask, meaning
start off with a `mask = 0b0001`, for each iteration of the loop, increase the mask to `mask = 0b1111`
And in the inner for loop, I shift the mask so that something like this happens

```
mask = 0b0001  //A
mask = 0b0010  //B
mask = 0b0100  //C
mask = 0b1000  //D
//The inner loop will finish here, and the mask length will become 2
mask = 0b0011  //AB
mask = 0b0110  //BC
mask = 0b1100  //CD
//etc.  The string representation is made by the function printForMask()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are shifting "mask" by 1 bit in your code.

Comment: @Daggerhunt Just added more info to the answer :D

Comment: Alright ... but what is the meaning of this if statement if(mask & 1), I understand that you are entering the charecters in the maskedstring[].

Comment: @Daggerhunt I'm checking if the last digit of the binary number is 0 or 1. If it is 1, I copy the character to the new string, if it is 0, I leave it alone.